# what's a good average of frames per second in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, frame-rate

I have a C++ program using openGL and it calculates the fps of my animation. However, I'm getting an average fps of 800 (which seems a little high). This is the code I'm putting in my display() function

```
int frames = 0;
int counter = 1;

display()
{
    //animation!

    //calculate fps
    if(TIME >= counter)
    {
            std::cout << "Frames at Second " << counter <<": " << frames << std::endl;
            frames = 0;
            counter++;
    }
    frames++;

}
```

Is my average of 800 fps okay, or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: There is no such thing as a good average. On my Radeon HD 7970, I can get > 12,000 FPS if I turn VSYNC off. It depends on the hardware, software, if you have VSYNC on, etc. It is better to measure frame time in milliseconds rather than the number of frames you draw in one second, since VSYNC will block. The best way to do this is to use Timer Queries (OpenGL 3.3 feature). If you use these, you can time individual parts of your frame and get much more useful information than the number of frames drawn in one second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nope, its correct. You are rendering as fast as possible. If you want the typical 60 fps try putting on vsync